# Why can't this Test::Unit test preserve the model across `post :create`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, testunit

I have two models: `User` and `Topic`. Users can have many topics and topics belong to one user.

In my Topics controller, I'm trying to test the create action for a valid topic:

**The Test**

```
  # topics_controller.test.rb
  def test_create_valid
    sign_in Factory(:user) # Devise will redirect you to the login page otherwise.
    topic = Factory.build :topic
    post :create, :topic => topic
    assert_redirected_to topic_path(assigns(:topic))
  end
```

**The Factory** (Factory Girl)

```
# factories.rb
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:username) { |n| "foo#{n}"}
  f.password "password"
  f.password_confirmation { |u| u.password}
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com"}
end

Factory.define :topic do |f|
  f.name "test topic"
  f.association :creator, :factory => :user
end
```

**The Test Output**

```
ERROR test_create_valid (0.59s) 
      ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"topics", :id=>#<Topic id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, creator_id: 1>}
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:425:in `raise_routing_error'
```

In the test, `topic.valid?` is true and `topic.name` has a value from the factory.

However, the post doesn't seem to make it past `post :create, :topic => topic`. It looks like it's never saved in the database since it doesn't even have an id in the test output.

**Edit**: Even if I bypass the Factory for the new topic, it doesn't work.

```
  def test_create_valid
    @user = Factory :user
    sign_in @user
    topic = @user.topics.build(:name => "Valid name.")
    post :create, :topic => topic
    assert_redirected_to topic_path(assigns(:topic))
  end
```

Results in the same test error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post` method here expects parameters as the second argument, not objects. This is because the `create` action in your controller is going to be using the `params` method to retrieve these parameters and use them in the process of creating a new topic, using code like this:

```
Topic.new(params[:topic])
```

So therefore your `params[:topic]` needs to be the *attributes* of the project you want to create, not an existing `Topic` object. However, you could use `Factory.build :topic` to get an instantiated `Topic` object and then do this to make it work:

```
post :create, :topic => topic.attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so far beyond me, but I apparently had to manually set the attribute in the `post :create` params. Seems pretty counter-intuitive given that `:topic => topic` is such a Rails idiom.

```
  def test_create_valid
    sign_in @user
    topic = Factory.build :topic
    post :create, :topic => {:name => topic.name}
    assert_redirected_to topic_path(assigns(:topic))
  end
```

Hopefully someone can shed some light on why `post :create, :topic => topic` wouldn't work.